# Teechart Gantt date in C++

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, teechart, gantt-chart

i'm a newbie and i'm working on a C++ VCL project with a StringGrid and a GanttChart. What i want to do is to "update" the gantt bar automatically once a new data is entered into the StringGrid.

What i do first is to create a chart with bars with this command:

```
TGanttSeries *Series1;
 int i = 0;

Series1 = new TGanttSeries(this);
Series1->AddGantt(StrToDate(StringGridEd1->Cells[4][1]),StrToDate(StringGridEd1->Cells[5][1]), i,"Task"+IntToStr(i));
Series1->ParentChart = Chart1;
```

That's perfect for creating a chart but how do i update the gantt's bar date so the bar automatically resize itself? For example if the user enter 1 day, the gantt bar display only 1 day and when the user enter 5 day the gantt bar automatically "resize" itself from 1 to 5 days.

Is there any function or properties which can do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just replied you at Steema Software official forum ([here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16146&p=71712)).
I'm copying the answer here:

If I understand it correctly, you can update your series StartValues/EndValues at the StringGrid1SetEditText event. Ie:

```
TGanttSeries *Series1;

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
  StringGrid1->ColCount = 6;
  StringGrid1->RowCount = 2;
  StringGrid1->Cells[4][1] = "01/01/2016";
  StringGrid1->Cells[5][1] = "02/01/2016";
  StringGrid1->Options << goEditing;

  int i = 0;

  Series1 = new TGanttSeries(this);
  Series1->AddGantt(StrToDate(StringGrid1->Cells[4][1]),StrToDate(StringGrid1->Cells[5][1]), i,"Task"+IntToStr(i));
  Series1->ParentChart = Chart1;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::StringGrid1SetEditText(TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow,
          const UnicodeString Value)
{
  TDateTime tmp;

  if ((ACol==4) || (ACol==5)) {
    if (TryStrToDate(StringGrid1->Cells[ACol][ARow], tmp)) {
      if (ACol==4) {
        Series1->StartValues->Value[ARow-1] = tmp;
        Series1->StartValues->Modified = true;
      }
      else {
        Series1->EndValues->Value[ARow-1] = tmp;
        Series1->EndValues->Modified = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```